# ASP.Net: ASPNETDB can I implement LINQ to Sql with this DB?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, membership-provider

Very new to membership provider and just implemented on my new web site.  I thought it would be nice to be able to use LINQ to query the database.  Can I implement LINQ to SQL on that database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really be querying the database directly. There is a Membership API for that. It uses a pattern called the provider model which means that you can use the same API always and then swap out a different membership provider without having to change your site code.

You might want to do this to use an xml file, or a webservice, or an in-memory provider, but you should still be able to use the Membership API without having to worry about how the data is being retrieved.

If you do want to write some linq-to-sql code then you should write your own membershipprovider:

- http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+custom+membership+provider

BTW, If you are just getting started then you should be learning Entity Framework really because Linq-to-Sql has been kind of superseded by EF.

Answer (score 0):

All the things rtpHarry said are right, generally you would use the membership API whenever you are within your ASP.Net application.

However, if you are querying your membership DB from another application for some reason, for example if you had a WinForms admin application or something, then you certainly can use Linq to SQL (or Entity Framework).